# What is the Rank in the context of Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am reading Keras documentation and I am stuck and the following sentence

> Note: if the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then it is flattened prior to the initial dot product with kernel.

from:https://keras.io/layers/core/

What is the rank in Keras' context? I am familiar with the rank of a matrix, but I cannot really see what it is the rank of a tensor in Keras (or why should be relevant)

A practical example would be useful.

Comment: I assume that they do not refer to the definition of a rank of a matrix in the mathematical sense but rather mean the number of dimensions of the tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just the number of dimensions of a Tensor.

> The **rank** of a `tf.Tensor` object is its number of dimensions. Synonyms for rank include **order** or **degree** or **n-dimension**. Note that rank in TensorFlow is not the same as matrix rank in mathematics. [[...]](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensors#rank)

Answer (score 1):

It means the dimensions of the input tensor, and not the rank of the input matrix.